# Relax calculation not converging

Tags: density-functional-theory, cell-optimization

I am using a DFT+U+V approach and using a pseudohybrid
density functional for extended Hubbard Coulomb interactions along with GBRV ultrasoft pseudopotentials (PBEsol). This enables me to open a gap in III-V systems and I am currently working on defect calculations of GaSb. I ran relax calculations using pure DFT, extracted the atomic positions, and then inserted those positions into the DFT+U+V input file. However, when I run this system I am not able to converge. I have tried tweaking the convergence threshold, mixing beta, and force/total energy convergence threshold. None of this has yet to work and my total energies in the output oscillates. It seems to be trapped in a local minima.

Here is my input file:

```
  &control
   prefix       = 'gasb',
   calculation  = 'relax',
   verbosity    = 'high',
   disk_io      = 'low',
   pseudo_dir   = '/anvil/scratch/x-ashipley/PP/',
   outdir       = './temp',
 /
 &system
   ibrav = 1, celldm(1) = 22.898548945864921 ,
   nat = 64, ntyp = 2, nbnd = 600,
   ecutwfc = 25, ecutrho = 100,
   occupations = 'smearing', smearing = 'gauss', degauss = 0.005,
   nspin = 2,
   starting_magnetization(1) = 0,
   starting_magnetization(2) = 0,
   lda_plus_v = .true., lacbn0 = .true., acbn0_type = 2, U_projection_type = 'ortho-atomic', ehub_nn_distance = 3, ehub_pot_fix = .false., ehub_conv_thr = 1.0D-07, ehub_mixing = 0.7,
   ehub_l_choice(1,1) = 1, ehub_l_choice(1,2) = 1, ehub_l_choice(1,3) = 1, remove_ehub_u(1,1) = 0, remove_ehub_u(1,3) = 0,
   ehub_l_choice(2,1) = 1, ehub_l_choice(2,2) = 1, ehub_l_choice(2,3) = 1, remove_ehub_u(2,1) = 0, remove_ehub_u(2,3) = 0,
/
 &electrons
   diagonalization = 'david',
   conv_thr        =  1.0D-7,
   mixing_beta     =  0.7,
   mixing_mode = 'plain',
   startingwfc     = 'random',
   electron_maxstep = 600,
 /
&ions
 ion_dynamics = 'bfgs',
/
 ATOMIC_SPECIES
   Ga 0 ga_pbesol_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
   Sb 0 sb_pbesol_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
 ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Sb            0.0000000000       -0.0000000000        0.0000000000
Ga            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.5000000000
Ga            0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.0000000000
Ga            0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.5000000000
Ga            0.5000000000       -0.0000000000        0.0000000000
Ga            0.5000000000       -0.0000000000        0.5000000000
Ga            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.0000000000
Ga            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5000000000
Ga            0.0027308549        0.2538487641        0.2538487641
Ga           -0.0027308549        0.2538487641        0.7461512359
Ga           -0.0027308549        0.7461512359        0.2538487641
Ga            0.0027308549        0.7461512359        0.7461512359
Ga            0.5003054101        0.2506818502        0.2506818502
Ga            0.4996945899        0.2506818502        0.7493181498
Ga            0.4996945899        0.7493181498        0.2506818502
Ga            0.5003054101        0.7493181498        0.7493181498
Ga            0.2538487641        0.0027308549        0.2538487641
Ga            0.2538487641       -0.0027308549        0.7461512359
Ga            0.2506818502        0.5003054101        0.2506818502
Ga            0.2506818502        0.4996945899        0.7493181498
Ga            0.7461512359       -0.0027308549        0.2538487641
Ga            0.7461512359        0.0027308549        0.7461512359
Ga            0.7493181498        0.4996945899        0.2506818502
Ga            0.7493181498        0.5003054101        0.7493181498
Ga            0.2538487641        0.2538487641        0.0027308549
Ga            0.2506818502        0.2506818502        0.5003054101
Ga            0.2538487641        0.7461512359       -0.0027308549
Ga            0.2506818502        0.7493181498        0.4996945899
Ga            0.7461512359        0.2538487641       -0.0027308549
Ga            0.7493181498        0.2506818502        0.4996945899
Ga            0.7461512359        0.7461512359        0.0027308549
Ga            0.7493181498        0.7493181498        0.5003054101
Sb            0.1253968266        0.1253968266        0.3765742716
Sb            0.1364394521        0.1364394521        0.8635605479
Sb            0.1256303329        0.6232578537        0.3767421463
Sb            0.1253968266        0.6234257284        0.8746031734
Sb            0.6232578537        0.1256303329        0.3767421463
Sb            0.6234257284        0.1253968266        0.8746031734
Sb            0.6245864554        0.6245864554        0.3754135446
Sb            0.6232578537        0.6232578537        0.8743696671
Sb            0.1253968266        0.3765742716        0.1253968266
Sb            0.1256303329        0.3767421463        0.6232578537
Sb            0.1364394521        0.8635605479        0.1364394521
Sb            0.1253968266        0.8746031734        0.6234257284
Sb            0.6232578537        0.3767421463        0.1256303329
Sb            0.6245864554        0.3754135446        0.6245864554
Sb            0.6234257284        0.8746031734        0.1253968266
Sb            0.6232578537        0.8743696671        0.6232578537
Sb            0.3765742716        0.1253968266        0.1253968266
Sb            0.3767421463        0.1256303329        0.6232578537
Sb            0.3767421463        0.6232578537        0.1256303329
Sb            0.3754135446        0.6245864554        0.6245864554
Sb            0.8635605479        0.1364394521        0.1364394521
Sb            0.8746031734        0.1253968266        0.6234257284
Sb            0.8746031734        0.6234257284        0.1253968266
Sb            0.8743696671        0.6232578537        0.6232578537
Sb            0.3754135446        0.3754135446        0.3754135446
Sb            0.3767421463        0.3767421463        0.8743696671
Sb            0.3767421463        0.8743696671        0.3767421463
Sb            0.3765742716        0.8746031734        0.8746031734
Sb            0.8743696671        0.3767421463        0.3767421463
Sb            0.8746031734        0.3765742716        0.8746031734
Sb            0.8746031734        0.8746031734        0.3765742716
Sb            0.8635605479        0.8635605479        0.8635605479

K_POINTS automatic
  2 2 2 0 0 0
```

If anyone has any ideas on what I can change or adjust, I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: I am not a regular user of QE, but just wandering if the input structure is correctly described. You have Ga and then Sb in the ATOMIC_SPECIES, then the first atom in ATOMIC_POSITIONS is Sb, would that be correct in QE inputs?

Comment: This is a defect structure where a Ga is replaced with an Sb. To my knowledge, it shouldn't matter which position the Sb occupies in place of a Ga.